# How to create a non-SQLEXPRESS instance for SQL Server 2012 developer edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

After install I wanted to practice creating SQL Server Agent jobs, I know that you cannot do this on a SQL Server Express instance, so I'm wondering with my developer edition if it's possible to create a non-SQL Server Express instance, and if so how, thanks.

Comment: `SQL Server Developer Edition lets developers build almost any kind of database application on top of SQL Server. It's licensed for use as a development and test system, not as a production server, and is an ideal choice for people who build and test database applications.`

Comment: Since developer edition is not express edition, the answer is.... YES

Comment: But how do I do this?

Comment: You can do it in Management Studio.  There is a node for SQL Server Agent under each instance.

Comment: SQL Server Agent does not exist for SQL Express Instance.

Comment: You install SQL Server developer edition as per the installation instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized that I only had SQL Server 2012 Express edition by using:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('EDITION')
```

Using the link provided by Eralper I installed SQL Server 2014 developer edition and now have two instances of SQL Server, one is the the express for 2012, the other is the 2014 developer edition. Once I log in to the named instance I can finally see of course the SQL Server Agent node at the bottom.

Thanks everyone for all the help and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Please check following tutorial which shows [SQL Server 2016 installation](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2016/sql-server-2016-installation-on-windows-10.aspx) step by step

In general for all SQL Server versions the setup procedure is very similar.
You can exclude installing components like Reporting Services, Integration Services, Analysis Services and other optional components if you want to make the setup process simple

What you should install is Database Engine Services! You can exclude the other features under Database Engine if you check the screenshot I shared in the article.
And what is important is the Management Tools that you can use to connect db instance and execute queries, etc.

Although the above tutorial shares the download link, you can also refer to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2016 for SQL Server 2014 and 2012 download links as well

Comment: So since I already installed, I have to go and launch setup and reinstall Database Engine Services in Feature Selection as shown in the screen shot from your link?

Comment: If Developer Edition database services is installed, you had probably created a default instance which is not the express instance. If so, there should be two SQL Server instances on your server. One default instance "." and the other is "SQLExpress"